# how can i set classpath for external jar files in java?

Tags: java

I am using java1.6 without using any IDE.Now i want to use java Mail API for my purpose.So, i copied Mail.jar into `d:\externaljar` folder.

And also i have set the `classpath as set classpath=%classpath%;d:\externaljar;`

my jdk installation folder is : `c:\programfiles\jdk1.6`.

But i faced `package javax.mail does not exist during compilation.`

Please Guide me to get out of this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jar file itself must be in the classpath, and not just the directory containing it.

And the CLASSPATH environment variable is `CLASSPATH`, not `classpath`. My advice would be to never use it, though. Always use the `-classpath` (or `-cp`) option with javac or java to pass the classpath.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer the `-cp` option over the global `CLASSPATH` environment variable:

```
java -cp .;d:/externaljar/mail.jar my.application.App
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend against setting `CLASSPATH` and instead use the `-cp` flag:

```
javac -cp .;d:\externaljar\mail.jar whatever/package/YourClass.java
```

You may also use wildcarding:

```
javac -cp .;d:\externaljar\* whatever/package/YourClass.java
```

Running is the same thing, except you provide the classname with the `main` method.

```
java -cp .;d:\externaljar\* whatever.package.YourClass
```